# Core data crash add object to relation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a problem with core data that is crashing my app. This happens when i'm trying to add a object to a relationship.

```
    HOMUser *artist = [HOMUser GetUserWithDictionary:artistDict inContext:context];
    [self addMArtistsObject:artist];
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 25 beyond bounds [0 .. 24]'

The number 25 represents how many entities are in Core Data Model. This is the call stack. It goes far into the framework so i cannot debug a lot. This didn't happened since always. I've checked and rechecked the Core Data Model. Does anybody have a ideea about what can be wrong?

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x02c0e02e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02a33e7e objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x02bb00b4 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 196
3   CoreData                            0x0122ee2a -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _includeObject:intoPropertyWithKey:andIndex:] + 90
4   CoreData                            0x0122ed0e -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 590
5   CoreData                            0x0122fcb1 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:forChange:onSet:] + 273
6   CoreData                            0x0122e956 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 1878
7   CoreData                            0x0122e1f0 -[NSManagedObjectContext observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 400
8   Foundation                          0x021a6ce7 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 357
9   Foundation                          0x021c03f4 NSKeyValueDidChange + 456
10  Foundation                          0x022239c3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:] + 131
11  CoreData                            0x0122fb58 _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeywithSetMutation + 72
12  CoreData                            0x012a77e6 _sharedIMPL_addObjectToSet_core + 310
13  ???                                 0x0bcf1379 0x0 + 198120313
14  Product Name                        0x000acb39 -[HOMEvent initWithTitle:withArtist:withPlace:withWhen:withDescription:andWithOptionsLink:andWithLinkWith:andWithFriends:insertIntoContext:] + 1161
15  Product Name                        0x002315a3 -[HOMAddEventVCViewController postPressed:] + 8771
16  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02a47705 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
17  UIKit                               0x016b7920 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
18  UIKit                               0x016b78b8 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
19  UIKit                               0x01778671 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
20  UIKit                               0x01778bcf -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 578
21  UIKit                               0x01777d38 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 546
22  UIKit                               0x0197b213 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 7407
23  CoreFoundation                      0x02bd6afe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
24  CoreFoundation                      0x02bd6a3d __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 381
25  CoreFoundation                      0x02bb47c2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1106
26  CoreFoundation                      0x02bb3f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
27  CoreFoundation                      0x02bb3e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
28  GraphicsServices                    0x038247e3 GSEventRunModal + 88
29  GraphicsServices                    0x03824668 GSEventRun + 104
30  UIKit                               0x016b465c UIApplicationMain + 1211
```

Comment: You are trying to get something from position 25 in an array with 25 items, arrays count from 0 so the last item will be at position 24. Have you got a loop somewhere starting at 1 instead of 0

Comment: Hard to tell, but the call stack suggests that it has to do with the inverse of the relationship you're setting there.

Comment: Is MArtists relationship a NSOrderedSet?

Comment: @AdamRichardson: I am not trying to get anything out of an array. As you can see the objectatindex method is called from far intro the framework when it crashes.

Comment: @random  MArtists is not a NSOrderedSet it is a NSSet.

Comment: Sorry guys .. just figured it out. I was adding a HOMUser to the relation when it needed a HOMArtist. The HOMArtist inherits HOMUser but the init method was initializing a HOMUser.